# How to know if email was sent from intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity

In my app, I'm creating an intenet to send an email... it looks like this

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mBuilder.mEmail})
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mBuilder.mSubject)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(getBody()))
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, zipUri)
                        .setType("application/zip");
                mBuilder.mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        emailIntent, mBuilder.mContext.getString(R.string.send_using)));
```

I want to know if it's possible to know if the email was actually sent or not, so I can perform some actions after that happens.

If so, please explain me how and if possible add a code snippet, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if it's possible to know if the email was actually sent or not

No.

First, there is no requirement that the user chooses an email client for this `startActivity()` request.

Second, there is nothing in the `ACTION_SEND` protocol that lets the app offering to share the content know whether or not the user did anything with that content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try startActivityForResult() and see whether the resultcode changes depending on what the user did

Comment: Already have, and it returns RESULT_OK even if user cancels the email sending

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva no clue then